# show all the blocks added to the particular page?

Tags: 7, blocks

I've been tasked to remove a tracking javascript from a particular URL on our Drupal 7 website. I've grepped our site's codebase for the name of the javascript that's being loaded, but I don't see it.

I need to start combing through content, but I'm looking at making my task easier.

Sometimes our front-end devs will include scripts in blocks. I want to look at all the blocks that are included in my target URL, but I don't see how to do that in the interface.

It seems that I must look at each of our blocks and then see if it's added to the page. I wonder, however, if there is a page somewhere in the admin menu where I can enter the URL I'm looking at and see what blocks are being attached to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that there isn't such a page. But you can go to the block administration page and see a list of all blocks for the given theme. If there is a 'configure' link for the block, it's a block that was created through the admin interface, so you can go through them to try to find the block in question.

The other thing you can do is examine the HTML to find the HTML id for the block. This will give you an indication of which block it has been added to, or if it was even added through a block or not.